# Can I use k-means to cluster a non-complete graph?

Tags: python, algorithm, cluster-analysis, graph-theory, k-means

I want to cluster a **connected undirected graph** (not a complete graph) by using **k-means** clustering algorithm. I only saw k-means is used in a complete graph, but i'm not sure whether there is another way i can apply it in a non-complete graph or not.

So, is there anyone here know about this? And, if k-means cannot be applied in the connected undirected graph, which algorithm is good for clustering this kind of graph?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: K means is for continuous coordinate data. Using it on a graph matrix is rather dubious, although it will produce some result that isn't totally nonsense. But it has a weighting problem that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

K-means could be used for non-complete graph. The only things you need is to set the weights of the edges (distances between two nodes) to be very high (much higher than other weights that are connected).

To cluster the network, I suggest to use **MCL - a cluster algorithm for graphs** to do the cluster (https://micans.org/mcl/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, and sorry for late reply. But i don't understand what you meant by setting the weights of the edges (distances between two nodes) to be very high (much higher than other weights that are connected). Could you please explain me clearer than this?

Comment: For example, you have a network with 4 nodes, A, B, C, D. A connected to B (AB) and A connected to C (AC), and C connected to D (CD). Then do you should have weight of these three edges. If you do not have weights, then you can set the weights of these three edges to be 1.  Then you can set other edges such as AD, BC and so on and set the weights of these edges very large compare to 1, such as 1000.

Comment: Thank you. You're so kind. I think this idea will work for k-means to prevent a result that has unconnected nodes in a cluster, which is what I want, but I cannot implement this idea because it is not flexible.

Comment: So, I want to try another way by forcing the centroid to stay on the node only, which means place the initial centroid on the node, then the centroid moves to its neighboring node. Assume that each edge has weight(distance), by doing this i can use shortest path instead of Euclidean distance for calculating total square error and maybe this can generate clusters that always have connected nodes. Do you think there is any way to implement this idea or not? If it is possible, could you please tell me how?

Comment: I'am not quite understand you. But if you do not use K-means, just try MCL (https://micans.org/mcl/), this is a very good method to cluster networks.

Comment: In my problem, the number of cluster is given. Then, can MCL allow me to set the number of cluster in advance like in k-means? Because I used to search a little bit about MCL, and it seems this algorithm automatically clusters the graph without knowing the number of cluster in advance.

Comment: Oh, then I understand what you said yesterday, Yes, what you think can be implemented.  Just set all the centroid to stay on the node. When updating, also keep them on the node is OK

Comment: Thank you :) You are so kind.